# HTML Video autoplay not working with bxSlider on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, bxslider

So I've made this slider using bxSlider and it works great. Except on Chrome. In Chrome it doesn't read any of the attributes inside the `<video>` tag while nested inside the slider. So no autoplay and the controls are still available.

Here's the code, it's pretty straightforward:

```
<ul class="slider bxslider" id="slider">
    <li id="01" class="slide">
        <video autoplay loop muted poster="img/01.jpg">
            <source src="img/pickup.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="img/pickup.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </li>
    <li id="02" class="slide">
        <img src="img/02.jpg">
    </li>
</ul>
```

This works fine on every other browser. If I use the same code outside the slider `<ul>`, everything works. I've found some hacks using JS that should resolve the issue, but I'd prefer to solve this without using JS. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `video: true` and the fitvids.js plugin resolved the issue.